# Cannot import initializeApp of firebase-admin of on my nodejs/typescript app

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, firebase-admin

I've added firebase-admin v12.0.0 package to my app, here is what I've done so far:

```
import { initializeApp, credential } from 'firebase-admin';

/*.....*/

initializeApp({
   credential: credential.cert({
      projectId: '...',
      privateKey: '...',
      clientEmail: '...',
   }),
});
```

and in chrome developer console I have this

```
chunk-345H5RC3.js?v=d7e643dc:4896 Uncaught TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
    at node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/api-request.js (chunk-345H5RC3.js?v=d7e643dc:4896:59)
    at __require2 (chunk-S5KM4IGW.js?v=d7e643dc:18:50)
    at node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/app/credential-internal.js (chunk-345H5RC3.js?v=d7e643dc:28359:25)
    at __require2 (chunk-S5KM4IGW.js?v=d7e643dc:18:50)
    at node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/app/lifecycle.js (chunk-345H5RC3.js?v=d7e643dc:29277:33)
    at __require2 (chunk-S5KM4IGW.js?v=d7e643dc:18:50)
    at node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/app/firebase-namespace.js (firebase-admin.js?v=d7e643dc:100221:23)
    at __require2 (chunk-S5KM4IGW.js?v=d7e643dc:18:50)
    at node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/default-namespace.js (firebase-admin.js?v=d7e643dc:100429:32)
    at __require2 (chunk-S5KM4IGW.js?v=d7e643dc:18:50)
```

I use node v18.19.1

I expect that firebase-admin initialize correctly

So far I've changed version of node and firebase-admin, deleted node_modules and relaunch `npm install`

Comment: How are you building and running this?  Please edit the question to show all of the relevant instructions someone can follow to duplicate the behavior.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is what mine looks like with the same installation. I think the issue is the `credential: credential.cert`?

```
const config = {
  apiKey: "...",
  authDomain: "...",
  databaseURL: "...",
  projectId: "...",
  storageBucket: "...",
  messagingSenderId: "...",
  appId: "...",
  measurementId: "..."
}

const app = initializeApp(config);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but even with this fix I keep getting the same error

Comment: What about adding: `import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";` instead of `from 'firebase-admin';`

Comment: tell me if I am wrong but as what I want is to push  notifications I need to use `'firebase-admin'`?

Comment: Is this for cloud-functions or the front end?

Comment: hum, I am in the back end project that's why I was thinking to use firebase-admin

Comment: `import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";` With this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client#add-initialize-sdk


Also, in my cloud-functions backend I do:

`import * as admin from "firebase-admin";`
`admin.initializeApp();`